# Request Form - check if input is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to check if user entered something in input field
something like this:

```
string valuestr = Request.Form["name"];
if (valuestr == null)
{
    Response.Write("error");
}
else
{
    sendform();
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem? Just check if user entered something in input field

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: question is  that code posted below is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
if (Request.Form["name"] == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Form["name"]))
{
    Response.Write("error");
}
else
{
    sendform();
}
```

I have not executed it but sure it will work.

Comment: why you are checking null separately at first ? `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` checks for null also right ?

Comment: this doesn't work you have to convert it to string like this Request.Form[""].ToString() since it's ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

I cannot use c#.
But I think your code is something wrong.
use below the code.

```
string valuestr = Request.Form["name"];
    if (valuestr == null)
    {
        Response.Write("error"); 
    }else {  
        sendform();  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a request for the form "name" you could simply check the input using the id of the control. In that case it would look something like:

```
//Trimming the input control should account for whitespace
If(idOfInputControl.Text.Trim() == null)
{
   idOfErrorLabel.Text = "error";
}
Else
{
   sendForm();
}
```

In the way you have provided it would look something like this

```
string str = Request.Form["name"];
If (str.Trim() == null)
{
    Response.Write("error"); 
}
Else {  
    sendform();  
}
```

Lastly, using asp.net, all of this can be handled simply by using a validation control. Here is a website explaining how to use validation controls:
[http://www.dotnetfunda.com/](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article785-how-to-use-validation-controls-in-aspnet.aspx)

Here is a video tutorial of how to use validation controls:
[YouTube - Validation Control Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jv7TgKr6Qgw)

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone:

Request.Form throws an Exception if no field in the form is passed in the request.

Request.HasFormContentType can be useful in this case.

```
var myFormField = Request.HasFormContentType ? Request.Form["myFormField "] : string.Empty;
```